# Illegal start of expression (method)

Tags: java, methods, expression

Recently, I decided to learn a little bit of Java and I've been stumped at the first hurdle. Here is my extremely basic code:

```java
import java.util.Scanner;

class helloWorld {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner user_input = new Scanner(System.in);

        int a = 50;
        String first_name;
        String last_name;

        public static int funcName(int a, int b) {
        }
    }
}
```

As far as I can see, there are no errors. However, at compile time I receive this error:

```
Dominics-MacBook-Pro:helloworld dominicsore$ javac helloworld.java
helloworld.java:12: error: illegal start of expression
public static int funcName(int a, int b) {
^
helloworld.java:12: error: illegal start of expression
public static int funcName(int a, int b) {
       ^
helloworld.java:12: error: ';' expected
public static int funcName(int a, int b) {
             ^
helloworld.java:12: error: '.class' expected
public static int funcName(int a, int b) {
                               ^
helloworld.java:12: error: ';' expected
public static int funcName(int a, int b) {
                                ^
helloworld.java:12: error: ';' expected
public static int funcName(int a, int b) {
                                       ^
6 errors
```

I've searched and searched and all the usual responses are typos and misplaced brackets but as far as I can see this isn't the case.

Not sure if it will make any difference but I am on a mac, using the vim editor and I'm compiling from terminal.

Any advice is appreciated.

Comment: Java doesn't support nested methods. What are you attempting?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about fundamental syntax features which will not help anyone in the future. Syntax issues are inherently offtopic on Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`funcName` is being defined from within the main method, it must be outside it:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

class helloWorld{

    public static void main(String[] args){
        Scanner user_input = new Scanner(System.in);

        int a = 50;
        String first_name;
        String last_name;
    }
    public static int funcName(int a, int b) {

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You cannot declare a method inside another method. Move `funcName` outside of `main` method:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

class helloWorld{

    public static void main(String[] args){
        Scanner user_input = new Scanner(System.in);
        int a = 50;
        String first_name;
        String last_name;
        //do something more here, probably to call
        //to your funcName method
    }

    public static int funcName(int a, int b) {
        //method implementation
        //since it doesn't return anything (yet), I add this line
        //just for compilation purposes
        return 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: And a method with a return type must return something